# Display 2 scroll bar (use scrollable ) when empty data in dataTable?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have use scrollable in p:dataTable (primefaces 3.4.2). But when empty data it show 2 scroll bar at below table. How can i fix it ?

```
                        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{p_bean.lstDecDetail}" id="lstDecDetail" editable="false"
                                     paginatorTemplate="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.paginatorTemplate']}"
                                     scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200" scrollWidth="1608" resizableColumns="true" 
                                     rowsPerPageTemplate="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.rowsPerPageTemplate']}"
                                     currentPageReportTemplate="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.currentPageReportTemplate']}"
                                     paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" paginatorPosition="top"
                                     emptyMessage="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.emptyMessage']}" rowKey="#{item.rnum}"
                                     rows="#{sessionScope['ss_pagesize']}" lazy="true">
```

Can you see some pictures :
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bgqP_P4Ha_s/UtTruMkS7xI/AAAAAAAAArE/moGQEZd_5lM/w980-h289-no/Capture1.PNG

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-AtaA6mYMjD0/UtTruMWOGnI/AAAAAAAAArA/dlpdQcTQOu4/w674-h373-no/Capture2.PNG
Continue code :

```
...</p:dataTable>
                <p/>
                <p:commandButton icon="#{qlaBundle['button.icons.add']}"
                                 value="#{tdBundle['Tdkt_DecLevel1.button.labels.add']}"
                                 action="#{p_bean['preLoadDialog']}" styleClass="qla-buttons"
                                 update=":bodyForm:lstVoteObject,:bodyForm:insertDialog"
                                 process="decNo,decYear,decDate,effectiveDate,decSigner,decExecutive,decRecipient,content,level0p,level1p,@this"/>
                <p:button icon="#{qlaBundle['button.icons.delete']}" style="align:right"
                          value="#{qlaBundle['button.labels.delete']}" widgetVar="deleteButton"
                          onclick="deleteConfirmDialog.show();" href="#" styleClass="qla-buttons"
                          disabled="#{p_bean.delBtnDisabled}" id="btnDelete"/>
```

Comment: it seems that you have one bar for the datatable, and another bar for the component that is nesting that datatable. You can try to raise the width of the parent component, show us the rest of your code.

Comment: Okay. My code hasn't another bar near datatable. Because, when have data in dataTable, it has just one bar. can you see picture :https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-2ZNAVLnqTdU/UtY-Z-HeotI/AAAAAAAAAsE/BW4VhZdzhSs/w227-h339-no/dsf.png